# The reverse of a query in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following two table : A and B

B contain a foreign key to A:a_id.

I have the following query :

> SELECT `a`.* FROM `a` INNER JOIN `b` ON `b`.`a_id` = `a`.`id` WHERE
>   b.stuff=1 AND (QueryCheckingDateWithBFields)

I want to reverse the query so i did that :

> SELECT `a`.* FROM `a` INNER JOIN `b` ON `b`.`a_id` = `a`.`id` WHERE
>   b.stuff!=1 OR (!QueryCheckingDateWithBFields)

It works fine except for one problem. I'd like that my first query + my second query = all A table entry. But if there is no B with a `a_ID` of an A, this A will not be selected. How can i say "i also want the A that are not joined?"

Comment: If you want all elements in `a`; why not just remove the `INNER JOIN`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `left outer join` instead of the `inner join` and adjust your `where` clause to support the case when there is no `B`:

```
SELECT a.* FROM a LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON b.a_id = a.id
WHERE b.id == null OR (b.stuff = 1 AND (QueryCheckingDateWithBFields))

SELECT a.* FROM a LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON b.a_id = a.id
WHERE b.id == null OR b.stuff != 1 OR (!QueryCheckingDateWithBFields)
```

Comment: Great! I needed it only for the second query. From a logical point of view it would mean that when i want to have the complementary of a request i also need to take the join into account.

Answer (score 2):

Use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN